# How do I jump to specific sequences of characters in PyCharm via an inline searchbox?

Tags: pycharm, webstorm

In [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvTZbQ_hUZY&feature=player_detailpage#t=20) YouTube video (@ around :20) you'll see him bringing up an inline search box which overlays shortcut keys onto the matching results in the visible code.

I believe he's actually using Webstorm, but I would guess its also in PyCharm, but I don't know what it's called or how to invoke it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a built-in feature but the functionality added by the [AceJump](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7086?pr=pycharm) plugin.